# How to change port in marathon

Tags: mesos, marathon

I used following command to change the port

```
sudo ./bin/start --master local --zk zk://10.20.8.106:2181/marathon --http_port=7070
```

But it's not working, I am getting

> [scallop] Error: Unknown option 'http_port=7070'.

As I am accessing ubuntu through putty 
Is it necessary to give IP address of ubuntu machine instead of "local" in command .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should get rid of the `=` char like this:

```
sudo ./bin/start --master local --zk zk://10.20.8.106:2181/marathon --http_port 7070
```

Have a look at

- https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/command-line-flags.html

concerning all available options. Regarding the `--master` flag:

> --master (Required): The URL of the Mesos master. The format is a comma-delimited list of of hosts like zk://host1:port,host2:port/mesos. If using ZooKeeper, pay particular attention to the leading zk:// and trailing /mesos! If not using ZooKeeper, standard URLs like http://localhost are also acceptable.